# Cant’t append text file using PHP

Tags: php

I am doing a php tutorial, but one aspect doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

I can confirm that I do have write access for this folder in Apache.
The contents of the text file:

Harry Ginter, 8237 Barkwood Dr., Lexington, KY, 40501

Felicia Ginter, 8238 Barkwood Dr., Lexington, KY, 40501

Trinity Ginter, 8238 Barkwood Dr., Lexington, KY, 40501

Eva Coutermarsh, 8239 Barkwood Dr., Lexington, KY, 40501

Here is the super simple script that should work, but when I echo the file the contents don't change:

```
$newCustomer = "\nMitzy Ginter, 8240 Barkwood Dr., Lexington, KY, 40501";
//Open a file to append to.  First create a handle:
$fileAppend = fopen("customers2.txt", "a");
fwrite($fileAppend, $newCustomer);
fclose($fileAppend);  //close file
echo "<br>Current file contents: " . file_get_contents("customers2.txt");
```

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Any error logs to report?

Comment: _"I do have write access"_ The Apache user needs write access, not you. Dump `$fileAppend` and you'll probably see that it's false.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I laughed my heart out. Very apt reply.

Comment: I did a var_dump and it returns boolean false.  I also closely looked at the permissions and I think you are correct that this file cannot be written to.  I had falsely remembered that I set write permissions on all files in this folder, but I guess not.  Thank you!

Comment: After adjusting the permissions, I tried again and the file changes.  Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$txt = "truthisgod";
 $fileAppend= file_put_contents('customers2.txt', $newCustomer.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```